# Running a perl script with arguments after pbrun in a wrapper script

Tags: oracle, perl

```
$user="abcd"
$access="ohsdba";

my $log_file="abc.log";

my @pb_ohsdba="pbrun $access -u $user -t 1-2 2> /dev/null << EOF
echo `perl cpu_main.pl $user $log_file`
EOF";
$pb_out=system(@pb_ohsdba);
```

This is how i tried executing cpu_main.pl from a wrapper script. pbrun works fine but cpu_main.pl doesnt get executed when arguments are passed. However the script runs fine if there are no arguments passed to cpu_main.pl.

Only one line from cpu_main.pl gets executed if arguments are passed.Then the control is passed back to the wrapper script.

Is there anything wrong in the way i am doing it? Is there any other way out?

Comment: `cpu_main.pl` contains data?

Comment: It is just another perl script that has few subroutines.

Comment: update the perl file in your question

Comment: Consider it to be a script with just few print statements. Cant display the file here.

Answer (score 1):

```
$access="ohsdba";
my @pb_ohsdba="pbrun $access -u $user -t 1-2 2> /dev/null << EOF
perl /tmp/SRGAutomation/bin/cpu_main.pl $user $log_file
EOF";
$pb_out=system(@pb_ohsdba);
```

The path of the script needs to be given. This is because after pbrun the path changes.

However its always better to have a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of points to take care of in your script.

1. Start your script with strict and warnings pragma on. They are our friends like this

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   ```
2. Don't assign scalar data into an array like this

   ```
   @pb_ohsdba="pbrun ..."
   ```

   As per your intent pb_ohsdba should be a scalar variable $pb_ohsdba.
3. Try to make your code easy to understand and debug as much as possible. For example you can take the output of

   ```
   perl cpu_main.pl $user $log_file
   ```

   into a scalar variable and pass that to pbrun like this

   ```
   my $cpu_output = `perl cpu_main.pl $user $log_file`;
   my $pb_ohsdba="pbrun $access -u $user -t 1-2 2> /dev/null $cpu_output";
   ```

Comment: @Arunesh The backtick that you removed was needed as in the original code the output of perl cpu_man.pl ... was passed to pbrun. Please edit and add the backtick as it as intentional.

Comment: Please refer to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators. The first statement will execute the string which is delimited by backtick and store it into $cpu_output. $cpu_output will be interpolated into $pb_ohsdba. So no problem to pass this to system.

Comment: @Partha Pratim Mukherjee.. I have the use strict use warnings and other basics required. Even tried putting it in a scalar variable like u suggested. It doesnt work . pbrun itself doent work.